# Facebook API (for android) : does the userID remain when android app updates

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

According to [this documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading#upgrading_v2_0_user_ids), Facebook's userID is dependent of the app that requests the userID, i.e., the useriD is different for each app that requests the userID.

My question is the following. Will the userID remain the same for my app when:

- My app will be updated on the play store (or apple store)?
- A user uses another phone to login to my app via Facebook?

It is not clear to me how I can make sure that the userID will remain the same.

The reason I ask this question is that I would like to provide my users with Facebook auth to my app. However, I need to be able to identified each and every user with a unique identifier (in this case, it would be the userID). User's email or phone number can't be used as unique identifiers as it is not guarantied that users have filled these info on Facebook (even though it is one or the other, I would prefer to have another unique facebook-related identifier of my users).

Maybe I have misunderstood the documentation, in this case, I apologise and thank you for pointing me to the part of the doc that answers my questions.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is different for each Facebook app ID. So as long as you use the the same Facebook app ID it will not change.